# Why does AppleScript fail to change the desktop wallpaper when running from a full-screen mode window, even though it runs without any errors?

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-monterey

I'm testing an AppleScript to set a picture as my desktop wallpaper. When I launch it while my desktop is active and visible, it works well; the picture sets quickly. However, when I execute this script in a window that is in full-screen mode (after pressing the green button that moves the window to a new separate space in the mission control), the script executes without errors, but the wallpaper on my desktop remains unchanged. It doesn't update. Why could this be happening?

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell desktop 1
        set picture to "/Users/eugen/Pictures/wallpaper-desktop.png"
    end tell
end tell
```

I tried rewriting the script, but it didn't work as well.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set desktopCount to count of desktops
    repeat with i from 1 to desktopCount
        tell desktop i
            set picture to "/Users/eugen/Pictures/wallpaper-desktop.png"
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Then I modified the script to check for errors, but any of them were being thrown:

```
try
    tell application "System Events"
        tell desktop 1
            set picture to "/Users/eugen/Pictures/wallpaper-desktop.png"
        end tell
    end tell
on error errMsg
    display dialog "An error occurred: " & errMsg
end try
```

Granting permissions to the full-screen app I'm executing the script from didn't help as well:

[image: Security & Privacy]

I would appreciate any suggestions and hints.